# Creation of large pandas DataFrames from Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bigdata

I'm dealing with data on a fairly large scale. For reference, a given sample will have ~75,000,000 rows and 15,000-20,000 columns.

As of now, to conserve memory I've taken the approach of creating a list of Series (each column is a series, so ~15K-20K Series each containing ~250K rows). Then I create a SparseDataFrame containing every index within these series (because as you notice, this is a large but not very dense dataset). The issue is this becomes extremely slow, and appending each column to the dataset takes several minutes. To overcome this I've tried batching the merges as well (select a subset of the data, merge these to a DataFrame, which is then merged into my main DataFrame), but this approach is still too slow. Slow meaning it only processed ~4000 columns in a day, with each append causing subsequent appends to take longer as well.

One part which struck me as odd is why my column count of the main DataFrame affects the append speed. Because my main index already contains all entries it will ever see, I shouldn't have to lose time due to re-indexing.

In anycase, here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
precision = 6
df = []
for index, i in enumerate(raw):
    if i is None:
        break
    if index%1000 == 0:
        sys.stderr.write('Processed %s...\n' % index)
    df.append(pd.Series(dict([(np.round(mz, precision),int(intensity)) for mz, intensity in i.scans]), dtype='uint16', name=i.rt))

all_indices = set([])
for j in df:
    all_indices |= set(j.index.tolist())

print len(all_indices)
t = time.time()
main_df = pd.DataFrame(index=all_indices)
first = True
del all_indices
while df:
    subset = [df.pop() for i in xrange(10) if df]
    all_indices = set([])
    for j in subset:
        all_indices |= set(j.index.tolist())
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=all_indices)
    df2.sort_index(inplace=True, axis=0)
    df2.sort_index(inplace=True, axis=1)
    del all_indices
    ind=0
    while subset:
        t2 = time.time()
        ind+=1
        arr = subset.pop()
        df2[arr.name] = arr
        print ind,time.time()-t,time.time()-t2
    df2.reindex(main_df.index)
    t2 = time.time()
    for i in df2.columns:
        main_df[i] = df2[i]
    if first:
        main_df = main_df.to_sparse()
        first = False
    print 'join time', time.time()-t,time.time()-t2
    print len(df), 'entries remain'
```

Any advice on how I can load this large dataset quickly is appreciated, even if it means writing it to disk to some other format first/etc.

Some additional info:

1) Because of the number of columns, I can't use most traditional on-disk stores such as HDF.

2) The data will be queried across columns and rows when it is in use. So main_df.loc[row:row_end, col:col_end]. These aren't predictable block sizes so chunking isn't really an option. These lookups also need to be fast, on the order of ~10 a second to be realistically useful.

3) I have 32G of memory, so a SparseDataFrame I think is the best option since it fits in memory and allows fast lookups as needed. Just the creation of it is a pain at the moment.

Update:

I ended up using scipy sparse matrices and handling the indexing on my own for the time being. This results in appends at a constant rate of ~0.2 seconds which is acceptable (versus Pandas taking ~150seconds for my full dataset per append). I'd love to know how to make Pandas match this speed.

Comment: bcolz might be useful here.

Comment: Tried bcolz, was quite happy with its speed but ran into memoryerrors on an array of ~ 6.5B entries when reshaping the data to my array size (I made a 1d list of equal sizes, then reshaped it to the number of columns the data belongs to). The linear array takes only like ~250 megs of ram, but for some reason the reshaping went straight to hell.

Comment: I used rootdir as well as without rootdir with bcolz, both versions return a memoryerror though memory usage never goes about ~1.5G from my monitoring. Here's a traceback:    
   bt = bt.reshape((ilen, bt.shape[0]/ilen))
  File "bcolz/carray_ext.pyx", line 1597, in bcolz.carray_ext.carray.reshape (bcolz/carray_ext.c:20854)
  File "bcolz/carray_ext.pyx", line 1943, in bcolz.carray_ext.carray.__getitem__ (bcolz/carray_ext.c:24477)
MemoryError

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my bcolz knowledge to give any suggestions (except should you be using ctables instead of carrays?)  You might want to add ```numpy``` and other tags to hopefully get some more views.

Comment: Any new about this problem? A way to improve the performance?

Comment: Nothing new @cyril as far as I know. Just ended up using scipy instead.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I use scipy and I keep my index separately.